# sideEffect with useState and event Listener onMouseMove

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mouseevent, event-listener

I need to add an offset value in y to my mouse position, but when I add the offset value, the mouse position is sometime corrupted and the witness `<div></div>` disappear, plus the refresh is stopped until I move again my mouse.
When there is no value added, that's work fine.
I try to find a solution with `useRef`, `useEffect`, the value `prev`of `useState` but my knowledge in React is very limited, and I don't find any solution.
Here a snipped code to resume my problem.
and a link to see the problem in live :)
https://www.knupel.art/

and the code is here :
https://github.com/knupel/knupel_site/blob/master/src/components/image/image_zoom.js#L34

```js
function Test() {
   // other code

   // here the code probleme
   const [mouse, set_mouse] = useState({x:0,y:0});
   const mouse_move = (event) => {
     // let buf = {x:event.pageX, y: event.pageY} // work fine
     let buf = {x:event.pageX, y:event.pageY + 42} // work, but very bad
     set_mouse(buf);
  }

  const info_style = {
        zIndex: "999px",
        position: 'absolute',
        height: '20px',
        width: '20px',
        background: 'yellow',
        opacity: is_over ? 1 : 0,
        left: mouse.x,
        top:  mouse.y,
    }
  // other code
  return(
       <div style={container_style}>
            <div style={image_style} 
                    onMouseEnter={mouse_enter}
                    onMouseLeave={mouse_leave}
                    onMouseMove={mouse_move}>
                <GatsbyImage image={getImage(img)} alt={img.base}/>
            </div>
            <div style={info_style} ></div>
        </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what is it that you are trying to achieve, are you able to explain what is the desired outcome?

Comment: @AviCohenNehemia I try to have normal behavior for the `<div style={info_style} ></div>` but when I add the offset to y, the behavior became weird. see on my link https://www.knupel.art/  I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: note, the bug happens only when the mouse go down, or go right, not on left and up direction.

Comment: and that's start happens when the value is upper to 30. The more the value increases, the more it happens. And only when the value is substract.

Comment: the same behavior happen when I pass by transform:translate().